# Cakephp HABTM: Model not accessible in controller

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to work with HABTM association between Profiles and Qualifications tables.

Model: Profile.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Qualifications' => array(
        'className' => 'Qualification',
        'joinTable' => 'profile_qualifications',
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'qualification_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
        )
    );
}
```

Model: Qualification.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Qualification extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Profile' => array(
        'className' => 'Profile',
        'joinTable' => 'profile_qualifications',
        'foreignKey' => 'qualification_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        )
    );
}
```

Controller: ProfilesController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class ProfilesController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
        $qualifications = $this->Qualification->find('list'); /* Attempt 1 */
        $qualifications = $this->Profile->Qualification->find('list'); /* Attempt 2 */
        $qualifications = $this->Profile->ProfileQualification->Qualification->find('list'); /* Attempt 3 */
    }
}
```

All three attempts mentioned as comment have given me an error saying:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
File:  ~/app/Controller/ProfilesController.php
Line:  xxx
```

I want to know how can I generate a list of all entries in Qualifications table ?
Moreover, what is the mistake in my code right now ?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Profile Model, the alias of your HABTM relation with Qualification is "Qualifications", so inside the controller you have to use : $qualifications = $this->Profile->Qualifications->find('list'); or remove the plural from the model.

To prevent these kind of mistakes and save your time, it's really useful to use automatic code generation with the [cake bake console](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) or an [online CakePHP baking tool](http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/cakes/bake).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for pointing that out! :)
I did use cake bake console to create this model and then tried showing my smartness which turned really bad :(